# How can I use a re-implementation of C's rand() function

Tags: python, encryption, random

This week I got an assignment in Python course, which is related to information security but I've never learnt that before...How can I fill the code to satisfy this requirement:

Here uses a re-implementation of C's rand() function. For this challenge, we use the linear-congruential generator included in glibc. It has an internal 32-bit state next. When calling the RNG, the state is updated using:
next = ((next * 1103515245) + 12345) & 0x7fffffff
Then, the updated next is returned as the random number.
Challenge. Recover the plaintext of the challenge.

```
import os
import os.path
import sys
import struct
import argparse

from util import check_challenge

from crand import rand, srand
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Util.Padding import pad, unpad  # pkcs7 is standard


def byte_rand(numbytes):
    calls = (numbytes + 3) // 4
    randbytes = b''
    for i in range(calls):
        r = rand()
        randbytes += struct.pack('<I', r)

    return randbytes[:numbytes]


def enc_file(fname):
    iv = byte_rand(16)
    key = byte_rand(16)

    cipher = AES.new(key=key, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv)
    f = open(fname, 'rb')
    ct = cipher.encrypt(pad(f.read(), 16))
    f.close()

    with open(fname + '.enc', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(iv)
        f.write(ct)

    with open(fname + '.key', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(key)


def dec_file(fname):
    with open(fname + '.key', 'rb') as f:
        key = f.read()

    with open(fname + '.enc', 'rb') as f:
        iv = f.read(16)
        ct = f.read()

    cipher = AES.new(key=key, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv)

    try:
        pt = unpad(cipher.decrypt(ct), AES.block_size, style='pkcs7')
    except ValueError:
        print(fname + ': decryption failed, invalid padding')

    with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pt)


def solve_challenge(fname):
    with open(fname + '.enc', 'rb') as f:
        iv = f.read(16)
        ct = f.read()

    key = bytes(16)
    
#######################################################################
    #[enter your code here
########################################################################

    cipher = AES.new(key=key, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv)
    try:
        pt = unpad(cipher.decrypt(ct), AES.block_size, style='pkcs7')
    except ValueError:
        print(fname + ': decryption failed, invalid padding')
        return

    with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pt)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command', title='command')
    subparsers.required = True
    parser_e = subparsers.add_parser('e', help='encrypt')
    parser_e.add_argument('file', nargs='+')
    parser_d = subparsers.add_parser('d', help='decrypt')
    parser_d.add_argument('file', nargs='+')
    parser_c = subparsers.add_parser('c', help='challenge')
    parser_c.add_argument(
        'file',
        nargs='*',
        default=['challenge.enc'],
        help='default: challenge.enc')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    files = [
        t for t in args.file if (
            os.path.isfile(t) and not t.endswith('.key'))]

    rng_seed = struct.unpack('<I', os.urandom(4))[0]
    srand(rng_seed)

    if args.command == 'e':
        # we don't encrypt already encrypted files
        files = [t for t in files if not t.endswith('.enc')]
        if len(files) == 0:
            print('No valid files selected')
            return

        for f in files:
            enc_file(f)

        return

    if args.command == 'd':
        # we only want encrypted files
        files = [t[:-4] for t in files if t.endswith('.enc')]
        if len(files) == 0:
            print('No valid files selected')
            return

        for f in files:
            dec_file(f)

        return

    # challenge: decrypt without having the key
    if args.command == 'c':
        # we only want encrypted files
        files = [t[:-4] for t in files if t.endswith('.enc')]
        if len(files) == 0:
            print('No valid files selected')
            return

        for f in files:
            solve_challenge(f)
            check_challenge(f)

        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Actually I have no idea what was I expected to do, please give me some help, thanks....

Comment: Basically you're supposed to use the fact that the random number generated is predictable to obtain the keys and decrypt it.

Comment: Notice that, when a file is encrypted, the iv is generated from first from your `rand()` function, and then next the AES key is generated. Also, the iv is placed as the first 16 bytes of the encrypted file.